# How to detect event by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to file.
One HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>JavaScriptSolution</title>
    <script src='./script.js' charset='utf-8' defer='defer'></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id='A1' value='On Keydown' style='width:100px; height:50px; margin:30px;'/>

<input id='A2' value='On Keyress' style='width:100px; height:50px; margin:30px;'/>

<input id='A3' value='On Keyup' style='width:100px; height:50px; margin:30px;'/>

<input id='A4' value='On Focus' style='width:100px; height:50px; margin:30px;'/>

<input id='A5' value='On Blur' style='width:100px; height:50px; margin:30px;'/>

<div id='A6' style='width:100px; height:50px; margin:30px;'>
    On Click
</div>
<div id='A7' style='width:100px; height:50px; margin:30px;'>
    On Mouse Move
</div>
<div id='A8' style='width:100px; height:50px; margin:30px;'>
    On Mouse Over
</div>
<div id='A9' style='width:100px; height:50px; margin:30px;'>
    On Mouse Out
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And other one JavaScript:

```
function byid(id_name) 
{ 
    return document.getElementById(id_name); 
}

byid('A1').onkeydown=function a1(){ alert('On Keydown'); }
byid('A2').onkeypress=function a2(){ alert('On Keypress') ; }
byid('A3').onkeyup=function a3(){ alert('On Keyup') ; }
byid('A4').onfocus=function a4(){ alert('On Focus'); }
byid('A5').onblur=function a5(){ alert('On Blur') ; }
byid('A6').onclick=function a6(){ alert('On Click') ; }
byid('A7').onmousemove=function a7(){ alert('On Mouse Move') ; }
byid('A8').onmouseover=function a8(){ alert('On Mouse Over') ; }
byid('A9').onmouseout=function a9(){ alert('On Mouse Out') ; }
```

My script work great on Firefox, Safari, IE, Chrome.
But didn't work on Opera & Some Android Browser.
What's wrong in my script?

Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked the console in Opera?

Comment: Wrap it inside `window.onload = function() { ... };`

Comment: @ShadowWizard: the questioner would expect that `defer` would prevent that from being necessary - an explanation as to why that's necessary would be good.

Comment: Opera 16 (latest one) is just based on Chromium! Don't bother about old browser much! Offer user an update!

Comment: I wrap it inside window.onload. It's work fine!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy certain browsers will simply ignore the defer. Will post an answer though, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `defer='defer'` to the script tag should indeed wait until the page is fully loaded, but as it stands now, even these days not all browsers are supporting it i.e. they will ignore it, causing the elements to not exist when the code is executed.

Full list of browsers support can be seen [here](http://caniuse.com/script-defer). Snapshot:

[image]

You probably have old version of Opera or Opera mini, hence it didn't work.

To solve this just play it safe by using the very basic `window.onload` which works on all browsers:

```
window.onload = function() {
    byid('A1').onkeydown=function a1(){ alert('On Keydown'); }
    byid('A2').onkeypress=function a2(){ alert('On Keypress') ; }
    //...
};
```

Alternative way would be to place the script tag with the reference to your JS file in the very end of the document, right before the `</body>` tag - with or without `defer`.